# C# keyboard and word prediction

Tags: c#, caret

I'm currently developing a C# desktop application which is a simple virtual keyboard with word prediction facility.

The prediction process will start after typing the first three letters of the word, then provide the suggestions. I need to track the caret while typing, and I tried to use richTextBox events such as SelectionChanged but it requires regular expression check and position tracking manually ( declaring variables ... ).

My questions: is there any suggestions that can help me in doing this task ? What about Listeners? are they helpful?

Note: I have no long experience with .NET framework and I didn't use Listeners before.

Also note that the input method is eye gaze ! which means non of key- events will work !

Thank you.

Comment: Will this be in WPF or WinForms?

Comment: What's wrong with OSK.exe (On Screen Keyboard)?

Comment: @Nick maybe no word completion/suggestions?

Comment: OSK on Win7 does word completion - perhaps the O.P. is on an older platform.

Comment: @Nick we have to implement a stand alone app regardless the OS, and yes JordyvanEijkis right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this be in WPF or WinForms? I would tackle this problem as follows. Maybe not the fastest way but worth to try until you have something else.

OnKeyDown event of your RTB check if the last char was a space. If not get whole word from last space and check against list of words and update the list on screen.

to check where the cursor is at the time in your word just do the same as above and try to get the current word and than the indexof specific key.

Comment: OnKeyDown cannot be used since the user will use his eye gaze! so no of key- events will work and this is the major problem I'm facing. All I can do is to deal with caret position, am I right ?

Comment: ohh ok you can [get the CaretPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition.aspx) if you have a FlowDocument inside the RTB